# New Battery: Runs out at "10% left"

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

I installed a new Apple battery in my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011) myself (bought the battery [new from iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009-to-Mid-2012-Battery/IF163-019)).

Installation worked great, extra 4 hours of battery life - fantastic.

Then I decided to get all smarty-pants and "recalibrate the battery".  I let the battery run empty, and the system entered "deep sleep"/"hibernation" mode as expected.

THEN I broke it when I did an SMC reset, [as found here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

Ever since the SMC reset, when my battery meter in the menu bar gets to ~9%, the system completely shuts off without warning.  No hibernation, nothing - complete power off.

Can anyone tell me how to get the system to properly recognize that the battery is almost dead, so it enters deep-sleep as it used to?

Things I've tried: Resetting SMC again, running battery dead and charging back to full.
Battery Charge Cycle counts looks normal; here are possibly relevant specs form system profiler:

**Battery Info > Charge Information:**

```
Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5683
Health Information:
Cycle Count:    100
Condition:  Normal
```

**System Power Settings > Battery**

```
Hibernate Mode: 7
Reduce Brightness:  Yes
Standby Delay:  4200
Standby Enabled:    0
```

Comment: Have you tried recalibrating (yet again)? Remember to fully charge the battery, leave it for _at least 2 hours_, discharge it, and leave it in sleep/power down for at _least 5 hours_. Then recharge.

Comment: I believe so - both times (before & after SMC reset) I drained the battery I left it overnight, and then charged it by leaving it plugged in all day.  I can try again though...

Comment: Honestly I would write iFixit customer service, explain the issue and see if they can either replace it or offer a definitive fix.

Comment: Arc, where did you get these 2hr & 5hr times from?  I am doing that procedure right now, just curious about where you found that. Thanks.

Comment: Tried it yesterday, computer still dies (hard-power off) @ 7%.  It might be my imagination but the % at which it dies *might* be getting lower...   Is there a way to set the percentage at which it hibernates (ie. set it to hibernate at 10%)?

Comment: Tried it again - to no avail.  Will contact iFixIt next...  Currently considering the script here:  http://tidbits.com/article/9115  to force-hibernate at 10%.

Comment: What's with all the battery calibration?!?  [Apple specifically states](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14087?locale=en_US):  **If your portable Mac has a built-in battery, you don’t need to calibrate the battery.** What you have is an issue with the battery and your best course of action is what @SteveChambers recommended.

Comment: Agreed, doing the battery "calibration" caused all these unnecessary issues - I recommend you do not do that unless absolutely necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a new battery doesn’t work with your hardware - I would return it to the vendor or seek service. Some aftermarket batteries may not work properly and the failure you describe isn’t likely to be something you (or any technician) messed up with cabling or connectors not seated.

When you reset the SMC it perhaps did a full read of the battery details and something isn’t correct for it’s code to predict when to send the low voltage / low charge warnings and begin an orderly shutdown.

This failure mode is different than the shutting off too high a remaining change - but it could be the same fix - get another battery.

- [Battery on white MacBook shuts off abruptly after 30% charge is left](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10135/battery-on-white-macbook-shuts-off-abruptly-after-30-charge-is-left)

Comment: This was indeed correct, I replaced the battery (years ago) with an after-market (ie. used) Apple-branded one and things got a lot better.